# How often does allennlp's GradientDescentTrainer update a model?

Tags: allennlp

Does GradientDescentTrainer update model at the end of each epoch ? or does it update once after a forward pass over a batch?

Answer (score 0):

The `GradientDescentTrainer` updates the model every batch after the "backwards pass" (assuming you're not using gradient accumulation).